# How to increase copy activity performance in ADF for ACDOCA table?

Tags: azure-data-factory, partitioning, sap-erp

I am copying data from SAP to Azure Synapse dedicated pool. The table name is ACDOCA from SAP side.

When I try to copy data from ACDOCA to Synapse, firstly it took around 8 minutes to first byte and then failed with internal memory error due to large amount of data in this table.

I have tried partition on calendar date for other tables like BKPF (On CPUDT column) and the performance was increased.

But, I am not able to decide which column should I consider for date partition in Copy Activity in ADF. FYI, AEDAT and BLDAT are not able to resolve the performance issue.

**Why I am doing this:**

I need the latest data of ACDOCA table from SAP to Synapse daily AND I want to implement a incremental load on this table using date column.

Thanks

Comment: Which field are you using for incremental load **AEDAT** or **BLDAT**?

Comment: @Aswin, I am using AEDAT field for incremental load. But the problem is in initial load.

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: I guess it runs a SQL statement like `SELECT ... FROM ACDOCA WHERE ...` using the column you defined, so doesn't it depend on the primary key and indexes defined for the table `ACDOCA`, and on the database system used by your SAP software? Which is? Moreover, which SAP software and version do you use?

Comment: @SandraRossi, I get the options in Copy Activity in ADF like: RFC Fields, RFC Field Option. And I cannot query with `SELECT` statement. I have to define table name, RFC Fields, and RFC Field Option (Which is like where condition in SQL)

Comment: I just explained the concept behind it and why it's slow and failing. It's not about ADF. The answer requires knowledge about the concerned database and SAP ERP.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Document number as Delta pointer as ACDOCA or ACDOCU table entries doesn't get modified at all, always new document number gets added when there is new posting happens